# Como puedo ajusta un Menubar customizado en JavaFX para que sea adaptable?

Tags: css, java-swing, javafx, ingenieria-del-software, javafx-css

tengo un problema que no logro resolver con javaFX.

Deseo colocar un Menubar customizado en un software de caja que estoy disenando, logre que se viera bien en la version fullscreen pero cuando reduzco la pantalla los iconos de cierre, minimizar y ampliar pantalla se ocultan ya que en la version reducida tengo las dimensiones de 1200 de ancho y 760 de alto, esta ultima esta estatica en ese tamano ya que en el Main le coloque `stage.setMinHeight(760.0);` que es la altura minima en la que quiero que se vea.

Les coloco unas imagenes de ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la primera parte de la imagen muestro como se deberia ver el Menubar por parte y en la segunda parte hice un montaje de lo que me gustaria ver cuando la pantalla este en el minimo tamano.

me gustaria que fuese responsiva es la conclusion de esto.

Como contenendor use un `BordePane` y en la parte de arriba use un `Hbox`, intente usar un `GridPane` dentro del `Hbox` pero no funciono o quizas no lo configure adecuadamente.

Comment: Bienvenido , necesitamos un [ejemplo mínimo reproducible](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)